# How to make my Discord bot to answer my questions with a random answer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I try to make a Discord bot that picks a random response from an array of replies. I also want it to send an error message if the question is unknown or there are no arguments after the command.

I have the following code, but it doesn't work. It does get a random reply, but it can't find the question by the received argument (`args[0]`).

```js
module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, bot, sendMessage) => {
  var array1 = ["reply1"];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length);

  const pergunta = parseInt(args[0], 10);
  if (!pergunta)
    return message.reply("make your question");

  message.channel.send("" + array1[rand] + "");
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying a make command likes vieirinha from loritta bot

Comment: one verification of characters in front of command

Comment: likes command=error & command+any character = reply

Comment: It's probably a good idea to give us a couple of examples in a way that's easy to understand. Like _"I want my bot to respond to the command `!cmd something` with something else"_

Comment: ah yeah 
like `!command any` = random reply from array

Comment: Be more clear about what you are trying to do, example, `!cmd hello`. Bot reply: how can I help you?

Comment: i trying to do an command `!cmd any word` Bot reply: `random reply from array`

Comment: So, do you have a problem with picking a random element from an array and send it to the discord channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a command that picks a random element from an array.

You can store the questions in an object. This way you can easily check (and access) if the user submitted question is valid. You can add an array of responses for every question, and pick one of them:

```js
function pickOne(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

const questions = {
  question1: {
    text: 'This is question one',
    replies: ['reply 1', 'reply 2', 'reply 3', 'reply 4', 'reply 5'],
  },
  question2: {
    text: 'This is question two',
    replies: ['reply 11', 'reply 12', 'reply 13', 'reply 14', 'reply 15'],
  },
};

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, bot, sendMessage) => {
  if (args.length === 0) {
    return message.reply('Oops, forgot your question?!');
  }

  const question = questions[args[0]];

  if (!question) {
    return message.reply("It seems that's not a question I can answer ");
  }

  const reply = pickOne(question.replies);
  return message.reply(reply);
};
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: yeah thats works, but i need a verification if exists some character in front of command
his replies some reply from array, if NOT exist his return `you not make a question`

Comment: Again, an example would be great.

Comment: likes `!cmd` = not replies or return a error message `!cmd question`
returns random reply from array

Comment: Okay, I've just updated my answer. Check if that's something you wanted.

Comment: thaaank you so much, its exactly i trying to do

Comment: Great, I'll try to update your question then :)